# What exactly is a cokernel? What's the motivation behind that, and what's its use? And why is it a quotient module?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, modules, ideals

Having a homomorphism of $R$-modules $f\colon M \rightarrow N$, we say a cokernel is $N/(\operatorname{im} f)$ which is a $R$-module (quotient).

Because $\operatorname{im} f\subset N$, this would mean that $\operatorname{im} f$ is an ideal.

So why is it an ideal?

Also, why do we even bother defining something like a cokernel? What's its use, what's the motivation behind a cokernel?

Comment: So it's not an "ideal", it's a *submodule*. You can easily check that it satisfies the criterion for being a submodule. This object shows up a lot in commutative algebra, pick up any book like Eisenbud for example and you will see it a lot. When things show up a lot in math, it's useful to give them a name. As for why it's called a "co" kernel, it's because it's the "dual" to kernels in category theory, see: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cokernel

Comment: The cokernel is the dual of the kernel, and has the dual universal property: given any other module $Q$ and a homomorphism $g\colon N\to Q$ such that $g\circ f$ is the zero map, then $g$ factors through the cokernel. Just like a morphism is one-to-one if and only if the kernel is trivial, a morphism is onto if and only if the cokernel is trivial; etc.

Comment: What's a dual? We haven't had category theory yet. With zero map you mean that it for any variable I put in I'll always get zero as the result of that map?

Comment: @user: While "dual" has a formal meaning in category theory, you can think of the way that certain concepts seem to come in pairs that are closely related to one another, after a suitable twist: sines and cosines; injective functions and surjective functions (for example, in the latter: if a composition is injective, the first map is injective; if a composition is surjective, the second map is surjective; injective functions have left inverses, surjective functions have right inverses, etc). Kernels and Cokernels are "connected" in that way. Yes, that's what "the zero map" means.

Comment: Ok, so it's kind of like a symmetry, but I still don't see in which kind of symmetry do cokernels stand/exist with respect to regular kernels? Basically what I see is that cokernels are like the complete opposite of kernels. Kernels are those elements from M for which the output of f is equal to zero. Whereas cokernels are elements from N which are cosets of the image of f? I think I kind of see the analogy

Comment: The kernel $N$ of $f$ is the submodule of $M$ such that if $g\colon P\to M$ is such that $f\circ g$ is the zero map, then $g$ “factors through” the embedding $i\colon N\hookrightarrow M$: there exists a unique morphism $G\colon P\to N$ such that $g = i\circ G$. The cokernel of $f$ has the dual property, as I indicated above: given any morphism $g\colon M\to Q$ such that $g\circ f$ is the zero map, then there exists a unique morphism $G\colon \mathrm{Coker}(f)\to Q$ such that $g=G\circ \pi$, where $\pi\colon M\to \mathrm{Coker}(f)$ is the canonical projection.

Comment: I'm gonna remember that if we actually start category theory, thanks!

Comment: One trivial motivation for the notion of kernel is that morphism is injective if its kernel is trivial. Similarly, a morphism is surjective if its cokernel is trivial.

Answer (score 3):

First off, $\operatorname{im}f$ is not an ideal but a submodule as $M$ and $N$ are $R$-modules and not rings. As you might recall the image of a ring homomorphism is not necessarily an ideal of the codomain as there is no reason for the image being closed under multiplication from the codomain.

---

As hinted in the comments the *co*kernel is fundamentally related to the notion of a kernel. For a more direct interpretation of this analogy we note the following proposition(s).

> **Fact.** Let $M,N$ be $R$-modules and $f\colon M\to N$ be a $R$-module homomorphism. $f$ is injective **iff** $\ker f=0$. $f$ is *surjective* **iff** $\operatorname{coker}f=0$.

I suppose you know the injectivitiy part and the surjectivity part is not that hard to prove either (I would advise you doing so if you haven't already). The crucial thing is that the quotient $N/\operatorname{im} f$ measures how far away $f$ is from being surjective in the same way the kernel measures how far away $f$ is from being injective. And this measurement can be best carried out in quotient form.

However, this quotient is not necessarily the definition of the cokernel. On a more abstract level many algebraic construction may be characterized by certain *universal properties*. Among those constructions are the kernel and the cokernel. These are related to annihilation of elements in a certain sense.

So consider $f\colon M\to N$ as before. Now take $\alpha\colon K\to M$ and $\beta\colon N\to L$ not arbitrary but such that $f\circ\alpha=0$ (i.e. the image of $\alpha$ is annihilated under $f$) and such that $\beta\circ f=0$ (i.e. the image of $f$ is annihilated under $\beta$). Here $0$ denotes the trivial map sending everything to $0$.
The kernel is then characterized as pair $(\ker f,\iota\colon\ker f\to M)$ so that for any such $\alpha$ there is *unique* $\overline\alpha\colon K\to\ker f$ with $\iota\circ\overline\alpha=\alpha$. The cokernel on the other hand is a pair $(\operatorname{coker}f,\pi\colon M\to\operatorname{coker}f)$ so that there is an *unique* $\overline\beta\colon\operatorname{coker}f\to L$ with $\overline\beta\circ\pi=\beta$.
In both cases, any homomorphism with a certain property factors uniquely through these objects. And both definitions share this common core but are somehow mirrored (the word "dual" appeared in the comments). Interestingly enough: kernel and cokernel are uniquely up to unique isomorphism charaterized by these definitions (called *universal properties*). So they really capture the essence of these objects.

One can show that these charaterizations correspond to our usual definition of kernel and we can show that the cokernel of $f$ is simply the quotient module $N/\operatorname{im}f$! Indeed, take $\beta$ as above at note that $\beta\circ f=0$ implies that $\operatorname{im}f\subseteq\ker\beta$. By the homomorphism theorem this implies that there is a $\overline\beta\colon N/\operatorname{im}f\to L$ so that $\overline\beta\circ\pi=\beta$, where $\pi$ is the usual projection. Moreover, this $\overline\beta$ is unique (the homomorphism theroem really is just another universal property; namely, the one of the quotient). So our quotient really is the cokernel in this more abstract setting.

On a final note: The defining universal property only tells you what an object should do *if* it actually exists. The quotient construction only works well as $R$-modules always admit quotients. This thing becomes more complicated when considering the case of groups as the image of group homomorphism is not necessarily a normal subgroup and hence the quotient might not be defined to begin with. Cokernels, however, do exists for groups but are defined explictly constructed slightly different (Hint: Is there a way of extending the image until the resulting subgroup is normal; and what does this imply for the ability of cokernels to detect surjectivity?).